# Search with Elasticsearch, return all records on visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to create search page with elasticsearch and Tire in a Rails 4 app. What i want to accomplish is that if a user visits /crews, the system shows crew listing page with facet search etc and 20 last added records loaded. So when the user first hits the page Elasticsearch should return 20 records by default when no query given.

So in my index action for crews i call the search method

```
  def index
    @crews = Crew.search(params)
  end
```

This is my search method to return all values when no "query" is given:

```
  def self.search(params={})

    tire.search(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:query].present?
          # just list all if no query given
          must { string "*"} if params[:query].nil?
        end
      end

      filter :term, 'crew_status.name.exact' => params[:crew_status] if params[:crew_status].present?
      sort { by :updated_at, "desc" } if params[:query].blank?

      facet "status" do
        terms :crew_status_id
        terms 'crew_status.name.exact'
      end
      # raise to_curl
    end
  end
```

This works but when there no records found in Elasticsearch, Tire will give an error "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query]" and this current solution also feels like a hack and i wonder how to accomplish my preferred behavior on the right way. That is just load all records if no query given and don't error out if the result is 0.

I've worked with Sunspot before and as i'm not mistaken the way i want to make my crews#index page to work is default in Sunspot. I hope somebody can help me with this and point me in the right direction to do this correctly in Tire / Elasticsearch.

Thanks in advance!

Greets, Daniel

Comment: You can try handling the same in view layer. I mean in index.html.erb, if @crews is nil you can just leave a message 'No results found' or something else and if not you can just display whatever you get

Comment: Thx, The error is happening on the model when i re-index a empty table, I understand this is a problem for Tire now.. not sure if i'm on the right track with the show all solution but it works.

Comment: Hey Daniel, have you managed to get any less hacky solution for the problem? I'm stuck exactly on same thing.

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't find a solution.. it was also because the project stopped and i didn't need to look into it anymore. I know there is a new gem http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/ruby-api/current/index.html its done by the same author as Tire but redone from scratch and maybe there is a different approach in there for this?